# Web2py just stopped working, failing to load even the admin page

Tags: python, web2py

I have been using web2py for over 8 months and it just stopped working. When I try to load the `admin/default/index` page it will keep loading and nothing happens. I connect to web2py via a local server by typing

```
python web2py.py -p 8200 -a 'passwordname' -1 0.0.0.0 -c ~/server.crt -k ~server.key
```

I haven't changed anything. What could the problem be? Is this an issue of web2py being outdated?

Comment: That's not a lot to go on. Probably an issue with the server, but hard to say without any details about the setup or diagnostics.

Comment: Ok..sorry about that i will edit the question

Comment: Have you confirmed that the web2py built-in server process is still running? Have you tried to restart it? Can you otherwise access the machine in question?

Comment: I can access the machine....i have restarted it many times but nothing happened

Comment: Hmm, maybe post on the Google Group for further help.